# Minimize the sum of diameters of 2-clustering graph

Tags: algorithms, clustering

Is there an algorithm with runtime $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ that for given weighted graph $G$, partition it into 2 cluster $C_1,C_2$ such that sum of diameters of two clusters minimized?

I find a paper with title

**"C. Monma and S. Suri, Partitioning points and graphs to minimize the maximum or the sum of
diameters"**

in some related papers  but i can't access to above paper to find out their's algorithm. The above paper solve my problem in $O(n^2)$.

Comment: This is [another](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01896987.pdf) paper; however with loose bounds.

Comment: Thanks. But the running time of the algorithm is not $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @Dmitry How it can be related to my problem?

Comment: @nirshahar The graph is weighted.